# MATLAB: Function not recognized by MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

I need to extract substring. I have found that unlike Python, it is not possible to use indices to extract a substring from a string variable. I have also found that MATLAB does not allow use of negative indices to access elements at end of a vector like Python does.

Looking into MATLAB documentation I have found this function:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ref/substr.html

However, when I enter this into the MATLAB, I get this:

```
>> substr
Unrecognized function or variable 'substr'.
```

I am using MATLAB R2022a. However, this function is not recognized. What could be the reason for this?

Also, are strings in MATLAB closer to the tedious strings of C language and not like the convinient entity they are in Python?

Comment: `substr` is part of the stateflow toolbox, you won’t have the function if you don’t have the toolbox.

Comment: It seems to me that this post is more of a complaint that MATLAB is not Python, than an actual question. Please [edit] the post to ask a question about programming. “How do I … ?” is a good way to phrase your question. And please include a [mre], we don’t even know if you are using actual strings objects or char vectors.

Comment: You could also just read the documentation to learn how to do things with strings in MATLAB: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html MATLAB documentation is **good**!

Comment: Wish I had time to be able to do that, anyway, whatever I needed to do with matlab is done.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of [substr](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ref/substr.html) says:

> The operator substr is supported only in Stateflow® charts that use C
> as the action language.

so this is not applicable in your case.

It is possible to get substrings of a string using indices. For example, you could use:

```
test_str = 'thisismyteststring'; % character array
test_str(9:12) % yields 'test'

test_str = "thisismyteststring"; % string array
extractBetween(test_str, 9, 12) % yields "test"
```

For more information on string handling, check out the documentation [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html).

Comment: See, str(1:2) actually works when str = 'hello' but not when str = "hello"; what big difference is the use of double quotes making here that the slice notation 1:2 works with one string but not the other? Both are strings as far as I know.

Comment: Nope, they're not.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 if you’d read the two short paragraphs at the top of the documentation page I linked for you, you would have known these are different things.